# Transforming XML with XSLT into XML need data grouped

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I've been working on this for the past few weeks and it's my first experience with XSLT so I'm surprised i've made it this far. My problem is that my XSL is working, but it is not grouping the results into their own node. 
My XML:

```
<r25:space_reservations pubdate="2013-10-11T19:52:51-05:00" xmlns:r25="http://www.collegenet.com/r25" xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <r25:space_reservation xl:href="reservation.xml?rsrv_id=4630649">
    <r25:reservation_start_dt>2013-10-11T08:25:00-05:00</r25:reservation_start_dt>
    <r25:reservation_end_dt>2013-10-11T09:15:00-05:00</r25:reservation_end_dt>
    <r25:act_head_count>25</r25:act_head_count>
    <r25:shared>F</r25:shared>
    <r25:reservation_state>1</r25:reservation_state>
    <r25:spaces xl:href="space.xml?space_id=582">
      <r25:space_id>582</r25:space_id>
      <r25:space_name>HARP 2060</r25:space_name>
      <r25:formal_name>Room 2060</r25:formal_name>
      <r25:related_space_id />
      <r25:related_space_name />
    </r25:spaces>
    <r25:layout_id>10</r25:layout_id>
    <r25:layout_name>SC - AUDIENCE</r25:layout_name>
    <r25:reservation_comment_id />
    <r25:reservation_comments />
    <r25:space_instruction_id>409729</r25:space_instruction_id>
    <r25:space_instructions></r25:space_instructions>
    <r25:registration_url />
    <r25:event xl:href="event.xml?event_id=88949">
      <r25:event_id>88949</r25:event_id>
      <r25:event_locator>2013-AAFBPD</r25:event_locator>
      <r25:event_name>Event Name here</r25:event_name>
      <r25:event_title>Event Title here</r25:event_title>
      <r25:event_type_name>COURSE-70</r25:event_type_name>
      <r25:event_type_class />
      <r25:organization_id xl:href="organization.xml?organization_id=37">37</r25:organization_id>
      <r25:organization_name>BUS</r25:organization_name>
      <r25:pre_event_dt>2013-10-11T08:25:00-05:00</r25:pre_event_dt>
      <r25:event_start_dt>2013-10-11T08:25:00-05:00</r25:event_start_dt>
      <r25:event_end_dt>2013-10-11T09:15:00-05:00</r25:event_end_dt>
      <r25:post_event_dt>2013-10-11T09:15:00-05:00</r25:post_event_dt>
      <r25:profile_id>269970</r25:profile_id>
      <r25:profile_name>70049-1</r25:profile_name>
      <r25:expected_count>25</r25:expected_count>
      <r25:registered_count>0</r25:registered_count>
    </r25:event>
    <r25:last_mod_dt>2013-08-09T14:28:20-05:00</r25:last_mod_dt>
  </r25:space_reservation>
  <r25:space_reservation xl:href="reservation.xml?rsrv_id=4630700">
    <r25:reservation_start_dt>2013-10-11T09:30:00-05:00</r25:reservation_start_dt>
    <r25:reservation_end_dt>2013-10-11T10:20:00-05:00</r25:reservation_end_dt>
    <r25:act_head_count>25</r25:act_head_count>
    <r25:shared>F</r25:shared>
    <r25:reservation_state>1</r25:reservation_state>
    <r25:spaces xl:href="space.xml?space_id=582">
      <r25:space_id>582</r25:space_id>
      <r25:space_name>HARP 2060</r25:space_name>
      <r25:formal_name>Room 2060</r25:formal_name>
      <r25:related_space_id />
      <r25:related_space_name />
    </r25:spaces>
    <r25:layout_id>10</r25:layout_id>
    <r25:layout_name>SC - AUDIENCE</r25:layout_name>
    <r25:reservation_comment_id />
    <r25:reservation_comments />
    <r25:space_instruction_id>410075</r25:space_instruction_id>
    <r25:space_instructions></r25:space_instructions>
    <r25:registration_url />
    <r25:event xl:href="event.xml?event_id=88950">
      <r25:event_id>88950</r25:event_id>
      <r25:event_locator>2013-AAFBPE</r25:event_locator>
      <r25:event_name>event name here</r25:event_name>
      <r25:event_title>event title here</r25:event_title>
      <r25:event_type_name>COURSE-70</r25:event_type_name>
      <r25:event_type_class />
      <r25:organization_id xl:href="organization.xml?organization_id=37">37</r25:organization_id>
      <r25:organization_name>BUS</r25:organization_name>
      <r25:pre_event_dt>2013-10-11T09:30:00-05:00</r25:pre_event_dt>
      <r25:event_start_dt>2013-10-11T09:30:00-05:00</r25:event_start_dt>
      <r25:event_end_dt>2013-10-11T10:20:00-05:00</r25:event_end_dt>
      <r25:post_event_dt>2013-10-11T10:20:00-05:00</r25:post_event_dt>
      <r25:profile_id>269971</r25:profile_id>
      <r25:profile_name>70050-1</r25:profile_name>
      <r25:expected_count>25</r25:expected_count>
      <r25:registered_count>0</r25:registered_count>
    </r25:event>
    <r25:last_mod_dt>2013-08-09T11:17:42-05:00</r25:last_mod_dt>
  </r25:space_reservation>
</r25:space_reservations>
```

My XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:r25="http://www.collegenet.com/r25">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:element name="r25data">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r25:space_reservations/r25:space_reservation/r25:spaces/r25:space_name"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r25:space_reservations/r25:space_reservation/r25:event/r25:event_name"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r25:space_reservations/r25:space_reservation/r25:event/r25:event_title"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r25:space_reservations/r25:space_reservation/r25:event/r25:event_start_dt"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r25:space_reservations/r25:space_reservation/r25:event/r25:event_end_dt"/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="r25:space_reservations/r25:space_reservation/r25:spaces/r25:space_name">
   <xsl:element name="room" >
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="r25:space_reservations/r25:space_reservation/r25:event/r25:event_name">
   <xsl:element name="eventName" >
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="r25:space_reservations/r25:space_reservation/r25:event/r25:event_title">
   <xsl:element name="eventTitle" >
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="r25:space_reservations/r25:space_reservation/r25:event/r25:event_start_dt">
   <xsl:element name="eventStart" >
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="r25:space_reservations/r25:space_reservation/r25:event/r25:event_end_dt">
   <xsl:element name="eventStart" >
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The results I'm getting are

```
<r25data>
<room></room>
<room></room>
<room></room>...
<eventName></eventName>
<eventName></eventName>
<eventName></eventName>
<eventName></eventName>....
```

etc, etc, etc through the different nodes I'm wanting

```
</r25data>
```

How can I get this XSL stylesheet to group each  in the   node?
Essentially what I'm looking to do is use XSL to pull out the data I need from the XML feed and give me an easy way to parse it out. All I need are the elements i've requested into it's own simpler XML feed that I can then parse (without the r25: namespace too!)
any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you!

Comment: Presumably you've worked this out by now, but it looks like you need a template for r25:space_reservation, since that is the parent of all the items you want information on. If you need more, just leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the XML.  Insert it into a table in SQL Server.  Read with a stored procedure where the node grouping will be much simpler and probably more performant.  SQL Server has robust support of XML as of 2008.  Also have you considered security?  The stored proc gives you more options.

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for, but thank you for responding!

Comment: I too am looking to group and/or sort by node. Have you solved?